# output text in .txt file into c++ console

Tags: c++

I'm new in programming. I had a tcms software which can export all the data into `.txt` file. I want to output the `.txt` file on c++ console (exactly the same as in the `.txt` file) But all I can do is this. Can anyone help me? Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string x;
    ifstream inFile;

    inFile.open("TEXT1.txt");
    if (!inFile) {
        cout << "Unable to open file";
        exit(1); // terminate with error
    }

    while (inFile >> x) {
        cout << x << endl ;
    }

    inFile.close();
}
```

The `TEXT1.txt` (and the output i desired) is

```
WLC013   SIN LEI CHADMIN DEPA      0     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     2.00
WLC008   NAI SOO CHADMIN DEPA      0     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     2.00
WLC017   SYLVESTER ADMIN DEPA      0     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     2.00
WLC004   CHANG KUEIADMIN DEPA      0     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     2.00
```

But I get output like this

```
WLC013    
SIN LEI CHADMIN DEPA         
0      
0.00      
0.00    
0.00    
0.00      
2.00      
WLC008    
NAI SOO CHADMIN DEPA        
...
```

And is it possible to edit the text file and add in the title for each of the column? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You're reading the file word by word, you need to read line by line, to get desired output.

```
while (getline(inFile,x)) {
cout << x << endl ;
}
```

For adding title/header or better formatting see [setw](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw)

Output it on console and then you can simply use output redirection `>` to a file.

Say you source name is `test.cpp`

`./test > new_file.txt` (linux)

or

`test.exe > new_file.txt` (windows)

This is a simplest approach. There can be other ways too.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
char directory[_MAX_PATH + 1];
char filename[_MAX_PATH + 1];

std::cout << "Please provide a directory Path: ";
std::cin.getline(directory, _MAX_PATH);

std::cout << "\nPlease provide a name for file: ";
std::cin.getline(filename, _MAX_PATH);

strcat(directory, filename);

std::ofstream file_out(directory);

if (!file_out) {
    std::cout << "Could not open.";
    return -1;
}

    std::cout << directory << "Was created\n";
    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; ++i) {
        std::cout << "(Press ENTER to EXIT): Please enter a line of text you 
        would like placed, in the document: ";
        char nest[100], *p;
        std::cin.getline(nest, _MAX_PATH);
        p = strtok(nest, "\n|\t|\r");

        while (p != nullptr) {
            p = strtok(nullptr, " ");
            std::cout << " The line (";
            file_out << nest << std::endl;
            std::cout << " )Line was successfully added.\n";
        }

    }
    file_out.close();
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please include some explanatory text with code in your answers.